# I am trying to create an address book program that will append user input to its appropriate list

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting past writing user input to my list what am I doing wrong here? This is an address book program that I am writing, the assignment is to create parallel lists that will store user input data in the appropriate list using a for or while loop. The program must also have a search function which you can see is at the bottom of the code. My issue that I am having is getting the program to store data within my lists. Unfortunately lists are something that give me lots of trouble I just cant seem to wrap my head around it no matter how much research I have done. The issue im running into is the append.data function when trying to write lastname and firstname to my list of names. what am I doing wrong?

```
#NICHOLAS SHAFFER
#5/11/2016
#MYADDRESSBOOK

def menu():

    index = 0
    size = 100
    count = 0

    answer = raw_input("Are You Creating An Entry [Press 1] \nOr Are You Searching An Entry [Press 2] ")
    if answer == "1" : 
        print ("This is where we create")
        append_data(index, size, count)

    elif answer == "2" :
        print ("this is where we search")
        search_database()

    name[size]
    phone[size]
    addresss[size]


# IF we are creating 
def append_data(index, size, count):



    # collect information
    for index in range(0, 100):
        optOut = 'no'
        while optOut == 'no':
            lastname[count] = raw_input("What is the persons last name? ")
            firstname[count] = raw_input("What is the persons first name? ")
            phone[count] = raw_input("What id the persons phone number? ")  
            address[count] = raw_input("What is the persons address? ")
            count = count + 1
            print 'Would you like to create another entry?'
            optOut = raw_input('Would you like to create another entry? [ENTER YES OR NO]:')
        if optOut == 'yes':
            menu()


    #create string to print to file
    #print temp1
    #print (firstname + " " + lastname + ", " + phone + ", " + email + ", " + address) 

    print listName[index]
    print listPhone[index]
    print listAddress[index]
    print 'file has been added to your addressbook sucessfuly'
    menu()

# SEARCHING FOR A RECORD
def search_database():

    searchcriteria = raw_input("Enter your search Criteria, name? phone, or address etc ")
    print searchcriteria
    if searchcriteria == "name":
        temp1 = open(listName[lastname, firstname],"r")
        print temp1
    if searchcriteria == "phone":
        temp1 = open(listPhone[0], "r")
        print temp1
    if searchcriteria == "address":
        temp1 = open(listAddress[0], "r")
        print temp1
    else:
        print "sorry you must enter a valid responce, try again."
        menu()

    for line in temp1:
        if searchcriteria in line:
            print line
            errorMessage()

# USER DID NOT PICK CREATE OR SEARCH 
def errorMessage():
        print ("Incorrect Answer")
        exit()


menu()
```

Comment: Please more explicit about the problem: what are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: Are You Creating An Entry [Press 1] 
Or Are You Searching An Entry [Press 2] 1
This is where we create
What is the persons last name? sha

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SChool LAB 4-1\addressbook.py", line 84, in <module>
    menu()
  File "C:\Users\SChool LAB 4-1\addressbook.py", line 14, in menu
    append_data(index, size, count)
  File "C:\Users\SChool LAB 4-1\addressbook.py", line 34, in append_data
    lastname[count] = raw_input("What is the persons last name? ")
NameError: global name 'lastname' is not defined
>>>

Comment: I am sorry for atrocity of a response I am new to this community.

Comment: refer to the function append_data. while testing my program I am running into an error storing the input into my sub list within the list of names. my list name should store first and last

Comment: It probably has something to do with you using open() on a list. open() is for files.

Comment: my error is coming from my 'append_data' function. specifically<br/> def append_data(index, size, count):<br/>



    # collect information
    for index in range(0, 100):
        optOut = 'no'
        while optOut == 'no':
            lastname[count] = raw_input("What is the persons last name? ")
            firstname[count] = raw_input("What is the persons first name? ")
            phone[count] = raw_input("What id the persons phone number? ")  
            address[count] = raw_input("What is the persons address? ")
            count = count + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message says it all:

> line 34, in append_data lastname[count]... NameError: global name 'lastname' is not defined

You'll get this same error if you type lastname[4] in any interpreter -- you've simply never defined a list called lastname, so you can't access items in it. In the short term, you can fix this with a line

```
lastname = list()
```

You're going to end up with more troubles though; `lastname` won't be accessible outside the function where you define it, neither will `listName`. I'd probably approach that by writing them into a data file/database, or maybe creating a quick class whose members will all have access to `self.lastname`.

Comment: I see what ive been doing wrong now. Thank you Noumenon.

Comment: You are right have been running into the issue where my lists are not accessible outside the declaration function. Is there any way to pass the lists to other functions or is my only option creating a data file attached to the program and writing the appropriate appends?

Comment: One way would be to pass every function an "address_repository" object that you can ask `repo.save_address(myAddress)`, `repo.get_all_addresses()` and so forth. The nice thing about that is that initially, `save_address` implementation could just look like `repo.lastname.append(myAddress.lastname)`, for testing. But later on, you could put in a real database and only change the `repo` object. Instead of changing all your functions to do database access, you'd just change `save_address` to say `database.query("INSERT INTO addresses.last_name {}".format(myAddress.lastname)`.

Comment: Thank you Noumenon you have greatly helped me. my appreciation thank you

Answer (score 0):

My final append for lists thanks again Noumenon

```
def append_data(index, size, count):

    lastnames = list()
    if count < size -1:
        lastname = raw_input("What is the persons last name? ")
        lastnames.append(lastname)
        print lastnames

    firstnames = list()
    if count < size - 1:
        firstname = raw_input("What is the persons first name? ")
        firstnames.append(firstname)
        print firstnames

    phones = list()
    if count < size - 1:
        phone = raw_input("What id the persons phone number? ")
        phones.append(phone)
        print phones

    addresss = list()
    if count < size - 1:
        address = raw_input("What is the persons address? ")
        addresss.append(address)
        print addresss

    listName = (lastnames, firstnames)    
    addressbook =(listName, phones, addresss)

    index = index + 1
    count = count + 1 
    print addressbook
    optOut = raw_input('Would you like to create another entry? [Enter YES or NO]: ')
    if optOut == 'YES':
        menu()

    print 'file has been added to your addressbook sucessfuly'
    menu()
```